# Github Action Skip Steps/Fall Through Syntax

Tags: bash, git, github, scripting, github-actions

I am setting up a github action workflow that should detect for particular file types in the commit. If the file types are detected, I'd like the workflow to continue, but if not, the job should skip those steps. I can't seem to find any documentation detailing a sort of Pass/fall through/branching logic. My next thought was to use an environment variable and evaluating that on subsequent steps. Has anyone had any similar experience?

```
- name: List Changes
        run: |
          CHANGE_LIST=$(git diff --name-only HEAD)
          echo $CHANGE_LIST
          for file in $CHANGE_LIST; do
            if [[ $file =~ .py ]];
            then
              LINT_LIST+=( "$file" )
              echo $file
            fi
          done
          if [[ -z ${LINT_LIST[*]} ]];
          then
            echo "No files to lint detected"
            exit 0
          fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by leveraging the environment variables available to github actions. I created an environment variable and saved it in the GitHub Environment:

```
echo "LINT_PROCEED=false" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

and was able to reference this in subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Actions offers some expression logic to handle situations like these: [Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions).

```
steps:
  ...
  - name: The job has succeeded
    if: ${{ success() }}
```

Some more detail on a slightly different use case, but this might help you: [Github Action triggered by success of a different action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516571/github-action-triggered-by-success-of-a-different-action).