# Github Action triggered by success of a different action

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I am trying to trigger a Github action to run after a successful run of a different action.

the 2 workflows are:

**Unit Test Action (Which runs first, and should trigger the Follow on Test action below**

```
name: unit-tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: "3.1.x"
      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test src/XXXXXXXXXX
```

**Follow on Test Action (This is just a test action)**

```
name: Test action triggered by previous action success

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - unit-tests
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  test-job:
    name: Test Step
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
      - run: echo "The follow on works!!"
```

The issue is that when this is triggered on a feature branch and not the default branch (as it should be because I want the actions to run all all branches) it doest work?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are both workflows present on the feature branch as well?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes they are. I have since figured out that you have to first merge the branch into your default branch and from then onwards it will work. However that is very frustrating because you cant test the trigger before merging to your default branch.

Comment: I have also read that it is possible to use "if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}" to only run the jobs if the previous workflow was successful. although i haven't been able to implement this successfully yet

Comment: You need to add it below the `test-job` line. [Here is an example](https://github.community/t/workflow-run-completed-event-triggered-by-failed-workflow/128001/2)

Comment: [Here is another example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/12-run-workflow.yml)

Answer (score 21):

As discussed in the comments:

**First**: It is necessary to have both workflows on the branch and to first merge the branch into your default branch, then onwards it will work.

**Second**: It is possible to use `if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}` to only run the jobs if the previous workflow was successful.

**Example**:

```
 on:
   workflow_run:
     workflows: ["Other Workflow Name"]
     types: [completed] #requested

 jobs:
   on-success:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
     steps:
       - run: echo "First workflow was a success"

   on-failure:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}
     steps:
       - run: echo "First workflow was a failure"
```

Comment: What if the trigger has both `on: workflow_run` _and_ `on: workflow_dispatch`? Is there a way to say "don't check for `workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'` if the workflow is manually triggered (there is no `workflow_run.conclusion` in that case)?

Comment: You could use something like `if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' || github.event.workflow_dispatch == 'true' }}` (I don't know if the exact syntax is this one)

Comment: thanks for that, sadly it didn't work. When the workflow was triggered by another workflow, everything worked fine, but when I ran it manually by dispatch, the workflow was "skipped".

Comment: I checked it here, and the correct syntax to check if an event is a workflow_dispatch is by using `github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch`. So the full expression would be: `if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a bunch. @GuiFalourd

Comment: Will this technique work across two separate repositories - e.g., successful run of workflow W1 in repo-A, could trigger the run of workflow W2 for repo-B?

Comment: This isn't support at the moment `gto406`. As stated on the documentation, this event is only triggerred by workflow files on the same repository default branch.

Comment: Thank you @GuiFalourd, I found this article - and was curious as to your thoughts on [this](https://medium.com/hostspaceng/triggering-workflows-in-another-repository-with-github-actions-4f581f8e0ceb) approach.

Comment: To trigger workflows from other repository, I prefer using the `workflow_dispatch` configuration as well, it's more customizable than the `repository_dispatch` configuration, and can be triggered by actions, gh cli, API or curl command directly. It's also interesting when you want to perform callback operations between repositories.